# how to filter for a range not just between

Tags: r, statistics

I used the code
filter(DaysInMilk %between% c("1", "90"))

However, I am worried about getting results that are days 1 - 86. I want to only include samples if they are days 1-90, like the entire range.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example so you can receive an answer to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like :

```
data %>% 
  group_by (sample) %>%
  filter(all(1:90 %in% DaysInMilk)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Easier to answer if you provide sample data :)!

Answer (score 0):

you first need to convert your column to numeric:

```
%>% mutate(DaysInMilk=as.numeric(DaysInMilk))%>%
filter( DaysInMilk >1 & DaysInMilk< 90))
```